# txt file import in DBeaver

Tags: sql, import, txt, dbeaver

I'm novice user of sql, I just learned about that database management is convenient using DBeaver in offline environment.

Questions are as follows:
Attempt to retrieve txt file data with \t delimiter from dbeaver.
When importing CSV file table from Dbeaver on the Internet(https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Data-Import-and-Replace/),
The following error occurs.
[image]

But what makes me more curious is that the result value is printed without any problems in preview data. **like below**
[image]

Is there any way to save the table without any errors?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us the problem SQL.

Comment: I'm afraid, but my problem is way before SQL, but rather a problem with the previous step, the Create table step.
I want to upload the txt file separated by '\t' to the sql database, just like the import CSV file as the URL I uploaded above.

Comment: Further more the error keeps return even if I create new table 
```error code: Error occurred during Create target metadata ```